# DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS is throwing ORA-06550,PLS-00306,ORA-06550 exception

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, ado.net

I am trying to gather stats of oracle schema using C# .net

```
 command = new OracleCommand();

 command.CommandText = "DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS";

 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ownname", "APP_PM"));
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("estimate_percent", 100));
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("degree", 30));
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("cascade", "TRUE"));

 appEngine.ExecuteSProc(command);
```

And I am getting this exception.

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

anyone any idea?

Comment: I think there is some problem with "cascade" parameter.

Comment: cascade accepts a boolean parameter, I think you might be sending a string

Comment: According to [this Microsoft support ticket](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306530) you can't pass BOOLEAN parameters using OracleParameter. You may need to use an anonymous PL/SQL block to run GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS from your C# app. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you @BobJarvis http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306530 ticket really helped I simply called this procedure inside other procedure as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with CASCADE parameter, if you cannot pass the BOOLEAN, alternatively, you can set the parameter value using [SET_PARAM procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i1048566).

Syntax :

```
DBMS_STATS.SET_PARAM (
   pname      IN    VARCHAR2, 
   pval       IN    VARCHAR2);
```

Bob's suggestion is good. You can wrap it in a PL/SQL anonymous block and execute it as a script.